# How to align second line in HTML Bullet point list

Tags: html, css

My Second bullet point "WiFi-enabled capabilities across the entire collection" shows up unaligned on **Outlook email**. The second line start with "entire" but it is indented to the right and not aligned exactly under the bullet point. How can I fix this?

```html
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 13.8334%; padding: 0px;" class="hide_on_mobile">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 66%; text-align: center; padding: 0px 10px 15px;" class="adonmobile2">
      <ul li padding: 10px 0 10px 20px; text-indent: -1em;>
        <li style="color: #090a0a; margin: 10px; padding: 0px; font-family: Avenir, Arial, san-serif; line-height: 150%; text-align: left;"><span class="font" style="color: #000000; font-size: 18px;"> Premium-grade stainless-steel interiors </span></li>
        <li style="color: #090a0a; margin: 10px; padding: 0px; font-family: Avenir, Arial, san-serif; line-height: 150%; text-align: left;"><span class="font" style="color: #000000; font-size: 18px;"> WiFi-enabled capabilities across the <span class="font" style="color: #000000; margin: 0px; text-align: left; font-size: 18px;"> entire collection </span> </span>
        </li>
        <li style="color: #090a0a; margin: 10px; padding: 0px; font-family: Avenir, Arial, san-serif; line-height: 150%; text-align: left;"><span class="font" style="color: #000000; font-size: 18px;"> Award-winning theater-style lighting </span></li>
        <li style="color: #090a0a; margin: 10px; padding: 0px; font-family: Avenir, Arial, san-serif; line-height: 150%; text-align: left;"><span class="font" style="color: #000000; font-size: 18px;"> Thermador exclusive Diamond Ice </span></li>
        <li style="color: #090a0a; margin: 10px; padding: 0px; font-family: Avenir, Arial, san-serif; line-height: 150%; text-align: left;"><span class="font" style="color: #000000; font-size: 18px;"> Intuitive Push-to-Open doors </span></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 17.1666%; padding: 0px;" class="hide_on_mobile">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

here

Comment: `<ul li padding: 10px 0 10px 20px; text-indent: -1em;>` - what is this? That is not correct HTML.

Comment: Why are you using a 2nd span to wrap the "entire collection" text? Why not a `<br>` or let it wrap naturally? Sounds like `.font` contains `display: block` or some other style that creates a new line.